# How to fill the screen with a video?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do this: 
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPb7f.jpg)

and here's the code:

```
  <div class="container" id="containervideo">
  <div id="video">
        <div class="box iframe-box">
         <div class="container">
          <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/67794477?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=0fb0d4" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#containervideo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left: 2px;
    top: 936px;
    z-index: -1000;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    #video { 

min-height: 100%;
    //min-width:100%; - if fit to width
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
left:0;
    }
```

the video always get centered on screen, it never fill both sides. Can anyone help me, please? :(

Comment: instead of `container` use `container-fluid`

Comment: why your iframe has width and height and trying controll it with css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the width and height attributes set on iframe. You can add a CSS rule that sets position of the iframe to absolute like so:

```css
.iframe-box iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box iframe-box">
   <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/67794477?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=0fb0d4" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked! :) Do you know how I take that black border off of the video? I must let it more similar to the image I posted.

Answer (score 0):

to get it to fill the screen just add

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```